# How to add buttons to each row of a datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "itemID" },
            { "data": "imagePath" },
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "icon" },
            { "data": "reporter" },
            { "data": "title" },
            { "data": "dateUploaded" },
            { "data": "dateReported" },
            { "data": "reportedReason" },
            { "data": "description" },
            { "data": "problem" },
            { "data": "numReports" },
            { "data": "deleteImage" } 
        ],
        "columnDefs": 
        [
            { 
                "targets": 0,
                "visible": false
            }, 
            {
                "targets": 1,
                 "visible": false    
            },
            {
                "targets": 2,
                "visible": false
            },
            {
                "data": null,
                "defaultContent": "<button>Delete</button>",
                "targets": -1
            }
         ]
    });
]);
```

**Note**: The final td in the tbody has been left blank.

```
<table id="example" class="sortable table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
         <?php 
            foreach($report_flag_info as $flag_info){ 
        ?>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>ItemID</th>
                <th>Image Path</th>
                <th>Image</th>
                <th>Reporter</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Image</th> 
                <th>Uploaded</th>
                <th>Reported</th>
                <th>Reason</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Problem</th>
                <th>No. Times Reported</th>
                <th>Delete Image</th> // I want the button to be in this column
            </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
              foreach($report as $flag_info){ 
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td></td>...
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The table in the html is populated by using a foreach loop to load the data from the server to the table. I tried the suggestion in the following links to 
solve the issue.

https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.defaultContent

[How do I add button on each row in datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471862/how-do-i-add-button-on-each-row-in-datatable)

https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html

[How add more then one button in each row in JQuery datatables and how to apply event on them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327933/how-add-more-then-one-button-in-each-row-in-jquery-datatables-and-how-to-apply-e)

Comment: Within your `foreach` loop, add a `<button>` element wherever it belongs.  Your loop is just producing HTML, so you can just... add button HTML where it makes sense to have a button.

Comment: have you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471862/how-do-i-add-button-on-each-row-in-datatable?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add button on each row in datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22471862/how-do-i-add-button-on-each-row-in-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that conumDefs Option was applied before columns.data, meant that columns.data Option config { "data": "deleteImage" }
 is overwriting the columnDefs option that is building the button. Changing { "data": "deleteImage" } to { "data": null } prevented
 the button being overwritten and hence, solved the problem.